# Why the push method doesn't work in this case : [].push

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to use the function `push()` directly in the array declaration, but its not working properly. In my example, my array return the value `2` :

```js
var j = ["b"].push("a");

document.write(j); // return 2
```

Why my array returns the value `2` instead of `["b", "a"]` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns:

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called

So `["b"]` you have an array. `["b"].push("a")`, yes it is now `["b", "a"]` but since you didn't assign it, you are left with the result of the `push` call which is its new length, 2. You can either assign it separately:

```
var j = ["b"];
j.push("a");
console.log(j);
```

Or use [.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.

```
var j = ["b"].concat("a");
console.log(j);
```

Comment: I've added information about the alternative. Feel free to rollback if you think it's too much :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my case the concat function is the best solution Thanks too @SecondRikudo

Answer (score 1):

The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.

```js
var j = ["b"].push("a");

console.table(j); // return 2
// this is correct
```